# Can I join different analysis from Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

i have an analysis 1 and analysis 2, Could I create an analysis 3 that contains analysis 1 and analysis 2? The analysis 1 and  the analysis 2 are from different datasets

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can embed analysis within the analysis. You might want to try using different sheets within one analysis rather than using multiple analyses. This will make navigation and filtering easier. A single analysis can support multiple datasets.